# Translation of "proceedings"

Tags: tradução

How do I translate "proceedings" to Portuguese? The word I mean is the one used to describe an event (usually scientific) involving a series of activities. For instance:

*Proceedings of the 15th international conference on Human-computer interaction*

Are there differences in translation from Brazil to Portugal regarding this word's usage?

Comment: In what context are you using proceedings? Isn't "Procedimentos" what you're looking for?

Comment: @aldux Good point. I will improve the question in a sec.

Comment: @aldux I added a context to the question. Tks mate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @aldux suggested, *procedimentos* would be a literal translation, which may work. However, I haven't been able to find "Procedimentos ..." as an actual title of conference proceedings.

Another related word is ***anais*** (which would be a literal translation of the English "annals"), which *is* used in the real world of conference proceedings, e.g. [Anais do CNMAC](http://www.sbmac.org.br/publi_cnmac.php), or [Anais do IX Congresso Brasileiro de Atividade Física e Saúde](http://periodicos.ufpel.edu.br/ojs2/index.php/RBAFS/article/view/2979). (For more examples, just Google.)

Another related word is *acta*, which strictly speaking is Latin, but apparently is used untranslated in Portuguese, too, e.g. [Acta de Engenharia de Pesca](http://seer.ibict.br/index.php?option=com_mtree&task=viewlink&link_id=2604&Itemid=109).

I think *anais* is best if you're looking for a good equivalent of "proceedings" (in the sense of conference proceedings), but if you're just providing a straight translation (of an English journal name), maybe the literal *procedimentos* is better.

Comment: Of course, *anais* makes me giggle...

Comment: For scientific conferences, "anais" is also the pattern used officialy in the ABNT (Brazilian Association of Technical Standards) rules. See [here](http://abntcatalogo.com.br/norma.aspx?ID=1825) (paid document).

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary definition:

> A record of the doings or transactions of a fraternal, academic, etc.,
>   society. [1](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proceeding)

Thus, it could be translate to: "Registro", "Ata", "Súmula" ou "Relatório":

> Relatório da 15ª conferência internacional de interação
>   Homem-Computador.

[[1] definition](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proceeding)